# Rewrite URL htaccess using GET method

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a page name ***detail.php*** which handle variable from `GET` method and the URL displayed will be like `domain.com/detail.php?v=tEDdwXC2dkq`, but I want change it into `domain.com/detail?v=tEDdwXC2dkq`.

***.htaccess***

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^domain.com/detail.php?v=(.+)$ domain.com/detail?v=$1
```

But it didn't work.
Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code.

```
RewriteEngine On
ReWriteRule ^detail/([a-zA-Z]+)$ detail.php?v=$1
```

Comment: it work for URL, and now I face new issue that ***CSS*** URL is broke, any solution?

Comment: yeah, the css file may be broke as well js and image file

Comment: Is there a solution to fix it?

Comment: try to use

../lib/css/style.css

Comment: try to put full url of the css with domain name. like.
domain.com/lib/css/style.css

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^domain/(.+)$ /detail?v=$1.
```

If not work, can refer to this link, might help =)
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

Comment: it work, but ***css*** file cannot be found :(
Should i write full `URL` for ***CSS*** file?
example: `lib/css/style.css` to `www.domain.com/lib/css/style.css`?

Comment: You dont put ur css file in domain, you should include it in the detail.php file. Nobody put css file in the domain.

Comment: I put css in the lib folder
root/lib/cs/here css file

Answer (score 1):

You have the arguments backwards for RewriteRule. You want to map /detail?v=whatever to /detail.php?v=whatever

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^detail$ /detail.php [QSA,L]
```

QSA - query string append. With this flag, it won't matter what the query string is, it will always be appended to detail.php. This makes it a little more flexible since you don't have to mess with .htaccess to add or remove query string parameters.

Comment: oh ya, my bad, but I have reversed the codes to `RewriteRule ^detail/v=(.+)$   detail.php?v=$1 [QSA,L]` but I face new issue that the ***CSS*** URL is broke.

Comment: what is the CSS URL? Do you have any other RewriteRule directives in place?

Comment: I have CSS URL like `lib/css/style.css` and I've try using full URL like `www.domain.com/lib/css/style.css` but it didn't work.

Comment: are there any errors in apache error log, what is the server response for /lib/css/style.css?

Comment: Also, looking at your responses to the various answers, what is the current form of your RewriteRule? It looks like you have tried all variations here, it's important to know which is in place. For example ^domain/(.+)$ will map all requests (including css, js and images) to detail. Whereas, ^detail/([a-zA-Z]+)$ and ^detail$ will not